# Handle PowerPoint Presenter View object Events programmatically in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, office-interop, powerpoint

[image]I created Add-In for PowerPoint which is working great in single screen but I need to use now double screen (Extended Mode) which has some issues and In my Add-In of PowerPoint, How can I handle the events of Presenter View Objects in Vb.net? lets suppose I want to control the events of these objects in presenter view pointed by red rectangles.

I want that when user click on presenter view object so my code should run rather than PowerPoint code.

Could someone please tell me how can I handle or can refer link.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Can you give us some code from your previous attempts? So that it's easier for us to give you some feedback.

Comment: What code did you try so far?

Comment: I am using two screens in extended mode and want to handle primary screen objects events not the secondary

Answer (score 0):

Can you make use of any of these events: (sorry, I only have the VBA function declarations to hand)

**SlideShowBegin** (2013, 2010, 2007, 2003, 2002, 2000)

Application SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

Occurs when a slide show starts. Is called for each slide show that starts.

**SlideShowEnd** (2013, 2010, 2007, 2003, 2002, 2000)

Application SlideShowEnd(ByVal Pres As Presentation)

Occurs when a slide show ends. Is called for each slide show that ends.

**SlideShowNextBuild** (2013, 2010, 2007, 2003, 2002, 2000)

Application SlideShowNextBuild(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

Occurs after the next build starts.

**SlideShowNextSlide** (2013, 2010, 2007, 2003, 2002, 2000)

Application SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

Occurs after showing the new slide.

**SlideSelectionChanged** (2013, 2010, 2007, 2003, 2002)

Application SlideSelectionChanged(ByVal SldRange As SlideRange)

Occurs after a slide or slide selection changes in any view except the Outline view.

**SlideShowNextClick** (2013, 2010, 2007, 2003, 2002)

Application SlideShowNextClick(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow, ByVal nEffect As Effect)

Occurs after the slide show window is clicked.

**SlideShowOnNext** (2013, 2010, 2007)

Application SlideShowOnNext(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

Occurs when the slide show navigates through next build within the current slide.

**SlideShowOnPrevious** (2013, 2010, 2007)

Application SlideShowOnPrevious(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

Occurs when the slide show navigates through previous build within the current slide.

Answer (score -1):

You can add event handler like you do in regular .Net applications.

Take a look at the [How to handle PowerPoint events by using Visual Basic .NET 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/824021) article which explains how to handle Microsoft Office PowerPoint events by using Microsoft Visual Basic .NET. The sample code is included.

```
    'Start PowerPoint and then make the PowerPoint window visible but minimized.
    oApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    'Add event handlers.
    AddHandler oApp.SlideShowBegin, AddressOf oApp_SlideShowBegin
    AddHandler oApp.SlideShowNextSlide, AddressOf oApp_SlideShowNextSlide
    AddHandler oApp.PresentationClose, AddressOf oApp_PresentationClose

    'Event Handlers

    Private Sub oApp_SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow)

    End Sub

    Private Sub oApp_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow)

    End Sub

    Private Sub oApp_PresentationClose(ByVal Pres As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation)


    End Sub
```

Comment: these are events which can be handled and I handled as well but I need objects of presenter I am using 2 screens I need to handle the objects of first screen